# Why is my do While loop causing an infinite loop?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I have this code that will modify a textfile depending on what the user inputs. The do while loop that is checking if choiceBack == 1 doesn't cause an infinite loop. However, the loop that is checking if idCheck is not true is causing an infinite loop. Why so?

```
bool idCheck = customerList.Where(m => m.iID.Contains(cC.iID)).Any();

do
{
    if (idCheck == true)
    { 
        (Chunk of code)

        Console.Write("User updated!");
        int choiceBack2 = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("1) Go Back");
            choiceBack2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            if (choiceBack2 == 1)
            {
                baristaLoggedIn();
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong option!");
            }
        } while (choiceBack2 != 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("username doesn't exist ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Enter ID: ");
    }
} while (idCheck != true);
```

Comment: Because `idCheck` do not change it's value during the loop.  It is set before the loop, and if value is `false` you will end up with infinite loop. Looks like you can put first line after `Enter ID:` line again.

Comment: I know what you're saying but i don't know how to fix it.. I know it's a lame mistake but spending hours on this assignment makes you really tired and not focus..

Answer (score 2):

Once `IdCheck == true` it will get into infinite loop. Because you never change `IdCheck` in your `if` statement `if(IdCheck == true)`. So your highest level `do while` is actually making loop infinite. At some point, you need to change IdCheck to `false` or remove that `do while` depending on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Why does the following loop run endessly?

```
var idCheck = false;

do
{
} while (!idCheck)
```

Do you see it now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the loop in your else statement- "Wrong Option". You can break it by putting "idCheck = false" in the else statement.